# java programming unary operator precedence

Tags: operator-precedence

I want know how the operator precedence works on below code.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=0,b;
        b= a++ + ++a * ++a;
        System.out.println(a+"   "+b);
    }

}
```

i got 3 6 as out put......But I din't understand how it works.
can anyone explain how it works.

Comment: What results did you expect? What results did you get? What part of the documentation did you not understand? Please show some effort and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks.

Comment: i got 3 6 as out put......But I din't understand how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a++ means that a is incremented after evaluation

++a means that a is incremented before evaluation

a is incremented three times in total, so its value is 3 after the expression is computed.

`b= a++ + ++a * ++a;` means that a is evaluated (0), then incremented, this (0) is added to the result of `++a * ++a`, which means that the left part is 2 (because a, which is 1 from before, is incremented before evaluation, thus is evaluated as 2), and the right part is 3 (a was 2, and is incremented before evaluation, so it evaluated as 3). Thus the result of the expression is 2 * 3 = 6.

To explain these incrementations a bit better:

`x = ++a;` is like `a = a + 1; x = a;`

`x = a++;` is like `x = a; a = a + 1;`